# Select2-Allow user to paste multiple values into dropdown from the existing dropdown data

Tags: razor, jquery-select2

I have a select2 implemented with data from server, and i need to let user paste multiple values to this select2 without allowing new values just the ones that already exist in dropdown.

javascript :

```
$(function() {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('.select2').select2({
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ', ', ' '],
            
        })

})
```

razor :

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.GroupUsersTo, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.UserTypes, new {@class = "select2", multiple="multiple", data_placeholder="Groupe utilisateurs",style="width: 100%;" })
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a good sleep i managed to understand the select2 better and i came with a solution based on the documentation https://select2.org/tagging.
I customized the createTag function and test if the text pasted already exists or not if it doesn't exist than i prevent the creation of new tag.

Code :

```
$(function() {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('#UsersTo').select2({

            tokenSeparators: [',', ', ', ' '],
            tags: true,
            createTag: function(params) {
              var length = $('#UsersTo option').filter(function() { 
                    return $(this).text() === params.term; 
                }).length;
              if (length == 0) {
                // Return null to disable tag creation
            return null;
            }

            return {
              id: params.term,
              text: params.term
            }
        }

        })
        

    });
```